# ASP.NET web application project, BLLs and namespaces

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-application-project

We have a large ASP.NET project which has 100s of BLL classes.  In our ObjectDataSources in the UI layer we have typename="".  Because we are converting to a web application project, the typename has to include the root namespace of the project.  This means we have 1000s of changes to make across lots of files.

Are there any better options out there to prevent us from having to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Open the solution in Visual Studio and do a find and replace in files across the solution.  I've done this before with this exact scenario.